# Git clone private repo in AWS ECS

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-fargate

I'm trying to download all private repos in my organisation.
I have a script that I want to run once a day using Fargate.
The problem I'm experiencing when running it is below:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I understand the error and in my dockerfile I add an ssh key to the image:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /backup
WORKDIR /backup
ADD . /backup/
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This is the script where I try to download all repos and upload them to S3 bucket:

```
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
DATE = str(date.today())


def archive(zipname, directory):
    return shutil.make_archive(zipname, 'zip', root_dir=directory,
                               base_dir=None)


def assume_role(role_to_assume, duration=900):
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

    assumed_role = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=role_to_assume,
        RoleSessionName='session',
        DurationSeconds=duration
    )
    credentials = assumed_role['Credentials']
    return (credentials['AccessKeyId'], credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
            credentials['SessionToken'])


def upload_to_s3(key, file_name, access_role):
    access_key, secret_key, session_token = assume_role(access_role)
    s3 = boto3.resource(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
        aws_session_token=session_token
    )
    s3.Bucket('zego-github-backup').put_object(
        Key=key,
        Body=file_name
    )
    print('Uploaded')


def login_github():
    g = Github(TOKEN)
    org = g.get_organization("Organisation").get_repos()
    role = "arn:aws:iam::7893729191287:role/Github_backup"
    for repo in org:
        repo_name = repo.name
        key = f"{repo_name} {DATE}.zip"
        ssh_url = repo.ssh_url
        os.system(f"GIT_SSH_COMMAND=\"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no\" git clone --depth 1 {ssh_url}")
        archive(f"{repo_name} {DATE}", repo_name)
        archived_file = open(key, 'rb')
        upload_to_s3(key, archived_file, role)
        shutil.rmtree(repo_name)
        os.remove(f"{repo_name} {DATE}.zip")
    print("Done")


login_github()
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I missing some steps?

Comment: Add "chmod 700 /root/.ssh/" - this won't solve your problem but is best practice. The error means that the keypair (id_rsa) which contains your private key does not match the public key stored on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I missed anything from your script but I didn't see you starting the ssh-agent anywhere and then adding the key to it.

From [GitHub's guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-linux),

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
$ ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple to use python tool that automatically backs up organisations' repositories in .zip format by saving public and private repositories and all their branches. If you want to do your backups every x amount of time, all you have to do is run the tool from a crontab on your server. It works with the Github API, if you have python on your AWS instance, the tool will be very useful : https://github.com/BuyWithCrypto/OneGitBackup